# How is the best way to add movies, as items into jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to add movies to createMovieTable function and to loop it in an array for creating HTML code via jquery function. Please help me to get it correctly 
I have an example, but not working properly:

```
var movies = {
  movie1: {
    movieTitle: 'Blade Runner 2049',
  },
  movie2: {
    movieTitle: 'Justice League',
  },
  movie3: {
    movieTitle: 'Thor: Ragnarok',
  }
};
$('.movies-table').createMovieTable(3, movies);
```

Here is my jquery function:

```
(function($) {$.fn.createMovieTable = function (moviesNum, movies){
var $table = $("<table class='table table-movie bg-darkpink m-0'><tbody class='tbody'></tbody></table>");
for(var i = 0; i < moviesNum; ++i){
  var $tableRow = $("<tr class='tr'></tr>");
  var $movieCounter = $("<th scope='row' class='align-middle text-center'><h2>"+ (i + 1) +"</h2></th>"),
  $moviePicture = $("<td><img src='movie-pics/" + (i + 1) + ".png' class='img-fluid img-thumbnail img-movie' alt='Responsive image'></td>"),
  $movieTitle = $("<td class='align-middle text-center'><h2 style='color: #647fde;'>" + movies.movie + [i + 1].movieTitle + "</h2><a class='custom-link' data-toggle='collapse' href=''#collapse-showtime-1' aria-expanded='false' aria-controls='collapseExample'>Edit Movie <i class='fa fa-caret-down' aria-hidden='true'></i></a></td>"),
  $deleteButton = $("<td class='align-middle text-center'><button type='button' class='btn custom-btn cb-dark-hover no-br delete-movie-btn'>Delete</button></td>");
  this.append($table);
  $('.tbody').append($tableRow);
  $($tableRow).append($movieCounter);
  $moviePicture.insertAfter($movieCounter);
  $movieTitle.insertAfter($moviePicture);
  $deleteButton.insertAfter($movieTitle);
}};})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere in your code you have this `movies.movie + [i + 1].movieTitle`. `movies.movie + [i + 1]` is not how you access a property of an object. If you want to use a `string` as an object property name, you can do that using something like this:

```
movies["movie" + (i + 1)]
```

This is called bracked notation. You can find out more about it [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

In my opinion, all this is better done using an array instead of an object.

So, you can have your movies information stored using something like this:

```
var movies = [{
        movieTitle: 'Blade Runner 2049',
      }, {
        movieTitle: 'Justice League',
      }, {
        movieTitle: 'Thor: Ragnarok',
      }];
```

And access it using something like this:

```
....
for(var i = 0; i < moviesNum; ++i){
   .... movies[i].movieTitle .....
}
```

If `movieTitle` is the only property of these objects you can even get rid of that and only use an array of strings instead of an array of objects.

Comment: I had movieTitle just to start, I will add more items, like description, time duration and so forth. I was looking for better way to get this resolved, and sure, array is much more convenient, thank you Titus.